# VIM Select Entire Line

Tags: vim

How do you select a single line in VIM, when your cursor as at some random point along that line?

I know you can do (v, $) to get to the end of the line, or (v, ^) to get to the start, but when you do (v,$,^) it logically doesn't select the whole line, it selects from cursor, until end, then switches it to cursor until beginning... So this approach fails of course.

Comment: I really recommend vimtutor to you. It was installed with your Vim and teaches you all the basic stuff about Vim. Just run `vimtutor` from the command line.

Comment: FDinoff, copy it, if I am remembering correctly.

Comment: If all you are doing is copying... isn't `yy` sufficient? Or without the newline `0y$`

Comment: FDinoff, yup you are right.  Thanks.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Capital `V` selects the current line in one key stroke; two, if you include the "shift" in <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

Comment: Your answer is slightly different than what the question describes: It includes the line's newline, i.e. when you `d`elete the selection, here the entire line disappears, whereas in the question's approach, the line is only cleared, but remains (empty).

Comment: Note that this is **not** what OP is look for. This selects the new line (`\r`) at the end of the line, but `0v$` doesn't. You could try it with `p` after your selection.

Answer (score 91):

<kbd>V</kbd> would be direct answer. However, I rarely need to do this because "selecting the current line" is generally part of a larger task. Example of such tasks includes copying the line and deleting the line. There's generally a better way to accomplish the task as a whole. The following are some of the tasks I can think of:

- copy the line: <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>
- delete the line: <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>
- indent the line: <kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd> or <kbd><</kbd><kbd><</kbd>
- select the current paragraph: <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> or <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>
- delete from the current line to the end of the file <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>
- highlight the current line to see where my cursor is: use `:set cursorline` in .vimrc file

One case in which I do use <kbd>V</kbd> is to select multiple lines that are not a paragraph or some other text object. In this case, there's a tip that might be useful for you: once in the selection mode, you can use <kbd>o</kbd> to jump the cursor between the start and the end of the selection.

Comment: I am usually have to select a line  to align a part of a text that couldn't be selected by an easier criteria.

Comment: Yes there will be case visual mode *V* is needed :)

Two more tips that might be helpful:
- if you want to indent the current line and the next line, use *>j*. To delete, use *dj*. I use this quite often.
- after you done some operation and you want to reselect the things you selected before, use *gv*. I use this all the time.

Answer (score 10):

While this might be more keystrokes.

If you are already in visual mode you can use `o` to go to the other end of the visual selection.

So you can type

```
v0o$
```

To select the whole line. Take a look at `:h visual-change`

---

However from the comments it seems you just want to copy the whole line.

Which would just be `yy`

Comment: add this `noremap \v v0o$` to your vimrc, so you can use as shortcut.

Answer (score 6):

Just change your order of operations. You almost have it.

```
^,v,$
```

Or as suggested by @Kent: because ^ goes to the first non-empty char, if the line has leading spaces:

```
0,v,$
```

Comment: I would press `0v$`, because `^` goes to the first **non-empty** char. if the line has leading spaces, this won't select the spaces.

Comment: kent, could you please explain the logic vim is using when it sees the code 0v$

Comment: `0 ` moves the cursor to the beginning of the line
`v ` enables visual mode
`$ ` goes to the end of the line

Comment: what mode you do enter this in?

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is super old, but I just had the same question. This thread came up first, but I found a different answer than any found here. Use 'V' to select whole lines. That easy. One character to select the whole current line.

Comment: Yes, but if you delete this, it will delete the entire line and remove it. What the OP wanted was that the content of the line is deleted, but the line remains there empty.